# 256color terminal flickering in Konsole

Tags: vim, terminal, colors, tcsh, konsole

I'm trying to setup 256 color mode at work for my Vim setup and it just refuses to work correctly. I'm using Konsole as my terminal emulator and my shell type is tcsh. I found a perl script named 256colors2.pl and ran it to see where I was currently at. My results looked like, where the line on the bottom of the white box under system colors flickers:

[image]

So then I followed the guide on the vim wiki to setup 256 colors for csh shells. The wiki says to set your TERM environment variable to "xterm-256color". After doing that, I still get the same results back from the 256colors2.pl script and now vim does this thing where lines appear all over the screen and flicker every second or so:

[image]

I'm at a loss now. I can find nothing else online that looks like my issue. Is there anyway to get 256 color mode working so I can use some sort of theme for vim?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what terminal emulator you're using.

Comment: Done. I'm using Konsole.

Comment: You don't *need* 256 colors to get syntax highlighting, the default 8 or 16 are enough. 256 colors gives you more bang for your bucks, though.

Comment: The perl script doesn't care what `TERM` is set to.  If it fails (as described in the question), your terminal simply doesn't support that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings menu, choose the profile to edit, then press the *Edit…* button highlighted in the screenshot and add these lines:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
COLORTERM=1
```

[image: Konsole]

(from [my colorscheme's wiki](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice/wiki/256-colors-and-you.#kde))

Comment: I don't think `COLORTERM` is used by anyone nowadays. But of course you definitely need `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: At least I needed it when I took that screenshot.